# UIScreen.main.bounds returning incorrect size on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple function to detect the orinatation and avoid face up - face down conflicts.

```
public func isLandscape() -> Bool {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
}
```

Works well on iPhone, but on iPad, it always (most of the time) opposite, meaning when the device is on landscape, the height is
bigger than the width. It just don't make any sense!.

In `viewDidAppear` when I call it, it returns the current origination, later on, if I call it, it return the wrong origination

I can do this workaround, but still doesn't make any sense

```
public func isLandscape(viewDidAppear: Bool = false) -> Bool {
    if DeviceType.isPhone {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    }
    return  viewDidAppear == true ?  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height :  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
}
```

Could anyone help me on that?

Comment: On which device are you testing?

Comment: on iPad Pro 12.9 inch. In viewDidAppear when I call it, it returns the current origination, later on, if I call it, it return the wrong origination

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong. Why don't you use traitCollectionDidChange delegate for changes in orientation and as  a starting point: UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape

Comment: I used that before,  but when `UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape` would be false if device is in landscape but also in `isFlat`. No so reliable

Comment: did you populated your plist with supported orientations?

Comment: I supported all orientations